# JavaScript iterate through class elements and select all except clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have 5 div elements. All of them with a similar onclick-function, that will "remove" the other divs except the clicked div.

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="divs" onclick="hide()"></div>
<div id="2" class="divs" onclick="hide()"></div>
<div id="3" class="divs" onclick="hide()"></div>
<div id="4" class="divs" onclick="hide()"></div>
<div id="5" class="divs" onclick="hide()"></div>
```

So this is what I tried:

JavaScript:

```
function hide(){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
    for(var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++){
        if(this != arrows[i]){
            arrows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

All this does, is removing every div, but the clicked element should stay. I'm aware that there's a ":not()" selector in jQuery, but I want to do this using JS. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Gonna assume ``var arrows = [document.getElementById('1'), ...``

Comment: Whops, copied the code from my workspace there and mixed it up with what I wrote here. The divs are images of arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `this` inside the `hide()` in html like `hide(this)`, and catch that as parameter in javascript function. This will pass current clicked DOM object to `hide` function and you can then use that to show that specific div.

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
<div id="2" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
<div id="3" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
<div id="4" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
<div id="5" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function hide(obj){
    var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
    for(var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++){
        if(obj != arrows[i]){
            arrows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Never use event handler content attributes. Use event listeners and it will work.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
function hide() {
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    if(this != divs[i]){
      divs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  div.addEventListener('click', hide);
});
```

```html
<div id="1" class="divs">1</div>
<div id="2" class="divs">2</div>
<div id="3" class="divs">3</div>
<div id="4" class="divs">4</div>
<div id="5" class="divs">5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but why not?

Comment: @Fred Because they are non-semantic, ugly, non-maintainable, uncompiled, and use a custom scope which can produce a great variety of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as

Html

```
<div id="1" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)">q</div>
<div id="2" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)">w</div>
<div id="3" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)">e</div>
<div id="4" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)">r</div>
<div id="5" class="divs" onclick="hide(this)">7</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
function hide(obj){
    var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
    for(var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++){
        if(obj != arrows[i]){
            arrows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick demonstration of what you want to achieve with some CSS so that you can see the effect:

```js
window.onload = () => {
 
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('divs');

  for(let div of divs) {
     div.onclick = (e) => {
       for(let visibleDiv of divs) {
              if(visibleDiv != e.target) {
               visibleDiv.style.display = "none";
              }
          }
      }
  }
  
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.divs {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e67e22
}
```

```html
<div class="container">    
    <div id="1" class="divs"></div>
    <div id="2" class="divs"></div>
    <div id="3" class="divs"></div>
    <div id="4" class="divs"></div>
    <div id="5" class="divs"></div>
</div>
```